# Linq to sql for groupby giving timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

In the below linq query first query is running fine.

```
1) var vrtemp = from details in context.GetQueryable<vw_FetchDTR>()
                                where details.App == id.ToString() 
                                select details;
```

but when I apply the groupby in the result of first query it's showing timeout.

```
2) var vrdetails = vrtemp.GroupBy(x => x.CompName);
```

note: vw_FetchDTR is a view

Comment: Did you check what the generated SQL looks like? Did you try profiling the query?

Comment: your query is taking much time try increasing TimeOut if using EntityFramework

Comment: check this link:http://joaodepaula.com/articles/context_timeout.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Linq to Sql generated not effective Sql query?
You can try to fetch all data before apply GroupBy operation.
Like this:

var vrdetails = vrtemp.ToList().GroupBy(x => x.CompName);

In that case you run GroupBy operation on server side. It will increase volume of transferred data but it can work more effective on Sql server